# Pegar o link do href no próprio href

Tags: php, jquery, css, html5, css3

Tenho o código abaixo

```
<?php $paginaCorrente = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY); ?>

<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="?l1" <?php if ($paginaCorrente=="l1") echo class='linkVisitado'";?>>Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="?l2" <?php if ($paginaCorrente=="l2") echo "class='linkVisitado'";?>>Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="?l3" <?php if ($paginaCorrente=="l3") echo "class='linkVisitado'";?>>Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="?l4" <?php if ($paginaCorrente=="l4") echo "class='linkVisitado'";?>>Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**$paginaCorrente** me retorna alguma coisa assim **parametro=algumacoisa**

O que eu gostaria de saber é se existe uma maneira de o link do href no próprio href de forma que ao invés de fazer

```
<a href="?l4" <?php if ($paginaCorrente=="l4") echo "class='linkVisitado'";?>>Link 4</a></li>
```

Eu faça:

```
<a href="?l4" <?php if ($paginaCorrente==LINK_DO_HREF) echo "class='linkVisitado'";?>>Link 4</a></li>
```

No caso acima preciso pegar o **l4** que está em **href="?l4"**

Será que existe uma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Não está dando para entender muito bem, pelo que percebi você quer pegar o valor de href e comparar no if dinamicamente é isso?, se for é possível somente com javascript

Comment: exatamente: preciso imprimir o valor de **href=""** dinamicamente em **$paginaCorrente==LINK_DO_HREF**. Em JavaScript, sabe me dizer como fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes da resposta, uma dica, usar esse if dentro do proprio elemento `a` fica feio. Em pouco casos, quando for necessário utlize o método **ternário** como neste exemplo:

`<a href="?l4" <?= ($paginaCorrente=="l4")?"class='linkVisitado'":"class=''"?>>Link 4</a></li>`

é conhecido mais como **if de uma linha**, você pode ver como funciona aqui:
https://sounoob.com.br/if-else-e-ternario-no-php/

Quanto a sua pergunta, não entendi o porque quer fazer isso. Não seria mais fácil fazer algo assim:

`$(document).ready(function(){ //ao carregar a pagina
    var x = <?= $paginacorrente ?>; //pega valor do get
    //alert(x); //da um alert aqui pra conferir se está com o valor correto
    $(document).find("a[href='"+x+"']").addClass('linkVisitado'); //procura por elementos a com href igual o get e adiciona a classe
});`

Não testei o código, mas deve funcionar, aí claro, você não precisa ter aquele monte de `if´s` lá nos seus **links**.

`<li><a href="?l1">Link 1</a></li>`

Comment: Ficou melhor. Mas pena que não dá para fazer direto com php ou css.

Comment: Somente com eles não. Os dois dependem do `javascript` para ler os elementos do **DOM**. O css consegue ver alterações no **DOM**, mas não le por conta própria os elementos da página. Recomendo dar uma estudada no `Sass`, do css, ou pesquisa por pré-compilador css. Aqui um exemplo https://tableless.com.br/usando-condicionais-sass-control-directives

Comment: Sim, eu vou dar uma estudada. Obrigado!

Comment: Fiz assim e funcionou: 
** <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="?l1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="?l2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="?l3">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="?l4">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
**
    $(document).find( "ul.menu a[href='<?php echo "?".$paginaCorrente ?>']" ).addClass( 'linkVisitado' );
**

Comment: Funciona sim, mas se você for ver esse código daqui um ano, ou se outro programador vir, vão achar bem confuso. Mas se deu certo blz.

Comment: Na verdfade, depois ds ul que carrega os itens da lista eu só coloquei  $(document).find( "ul.menu a[href='<?php echo "?".$paginaCorrente ?>']" ).addClass( 'linkVisitado' );